# What is Complex scalar type invalid as index value

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave, complex-numbers

I am using Octave on Linux to do some basic Matlab computations and I am getting the error mentioned in the title for the following piece of code:

```
for a = i:n
 aux = U(j,a)/U(a,a);
 % L(a,i) = aux;
end
```

I would like to mention that U is an n by n matrix and i is the index from another outer loop.

Thanks,
Daniel.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `i` and `j` as indices in Matlab is [not a good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab), since by default they represent `sqrt(-1)`. It would seem like either `i` or `j` are not initialized in your code, hence taking their default complex value.

Comment: Yes, and more complex than what I found out by myself. Thanks for the info! :)

Comment: I did not intend to repost the answer, found it out by trial but your answer is much more complete :) Thanks :D

Answer (score 5):

But you don't tell us what `j` is...

Is it possible there might be a problem with `j` as an index?

Note that both `i` and `j` are defined as `sqrt(-1)` by default. So if you use `j` as you have with no explicit predefinition, then you get a complex value, which fails to work as an index.